# How to assign values to an associative array in another array in React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, associative-array

I'm working on a react app to create multiple utm urls for ad campaigns and I'm having difficulty assigning values to the array in this.state. Here is how I establish the state:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        urlTabs: [
            {
                retailer: "",
                product: "",
                source: "",
                medium: "",
                campaign: "",
                keyword: "",
                identifier: "",
                notes: "",
                url: "",
                productOptions: []
            }
        ]
    }
    let tempTabs = [];
}
```

The app has the ability to have multiple urls that they are making at the same time which means that I needed to make state.urlTabs be an array of associative arrays. If they press a button I modify the state to have two arrays like such:

```
this.state = {
        urlTabs: [
            {
                retailer: "",
                product: "",
                source: "",
                medium: "",
                campaign: "",
                keyword: "",
                identifier: "",
                notes: "",
                url: "",
                productOptions: []
            },
            {
                retailer: "",
                product: "",
                source: "",
                medium: "",
                campaign: "",
                keyword: "",
                identifier: "",
                notes: "",
                url: "",
                productOptions: []
            }
        ]
    }
```

The issue I'm running into is when I'm trying to set any of the values. I do it by passing the event, input type and index as variables that then uses tempTabs to assign the individual value like such:

```
this.tempTabs[index]["source"] = event.target.value;
this.setState({
     urlTabs: this.tempTabs
}
```

However for some reason every value of source gets changed rather than the one that I selected via index. Why is that? Am I using wrong syntax to access the values? How do I set only one of the associative array's source instead of all of them?

Answer (score 0):

instead of creating a component level variable inside your class component like `this.tempTabs` try creating a variable like:

```
yourHandler = (e, idx) => {
  
  const tempTabs = {...this.state.urlTabs}

  tempTabs[idx]['source'] = e.currentTarget.value

  this.setState({ urlTabs: tempTabs })

}
```

i think the problem is that you are creating `tempTabs` in component level!

Comment: I gave this a try and making it a local variable inside of the function didn't change anything about how the array was modified. It still affects all of the source values in each array.

Comment: do you have any kind of didUpdate functionality in your component ?